# pdfpages error : includepdf + addtotoc / addtolist

Tags: tables, lists, languages, pdfpages

PDFpages produces this error. How could I fix it ?

```
Package pdfpages Warning: There's something wrong with the entries
(pdfpages)                of `addtotoc'. Not all entries were
(pdfpages)                processed. Check `addtotoc' on input line 144.


Package pdfpages Warning: There's something wrong with the entries
(pdfpages)                of `addtolist'. Not all entries were
(pdfpages)                processed. Check `addtolist' on input line 144.
```

Here is the code (mindmaps.pdf has 2 pages):

```
    %!TEX TS-program = pdflatex

    \PassOptionsToPackage{table,x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}

    \documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,usletter]{book}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}         

    \hypersetup{
         backref=true,   
         pagebackref=true, 
         hyperindex=true,  
         colorlinks=true,  
         breaklinks=true,  
         urlcolor= blue,   
         linkcolor= purple,  
         bookmarks=true,  
        pdftoolbar=true,        
        pdfmenubar=true,        
         bookmarksopen=true,            
         pdftitle={title of book},  
         pdfauthor={author of book},    
         pdfsubject={subject of book}
              } 


    %---------------------------- begin selection of language
    %  2 languages, here = second language selected
    \mtcselectlanguage{english}   % for minitoc

    %   \def\ColorSecondLanguage{\textcolor{DarkViolet}}  % produces an error, why ?
        \def\ColorSecondLanguage{}

    %\newcommand{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage}[2]{\ColorSecondLanguage{#2}}
    \newcommand{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage}[2]{#2}



    %---------------------------- begin macro for including a PDF document
    % includepdf syntax:
    %     addtotoc={⟨page number⟩,⟨section⟩, ⟨level⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}
    %     addtolist={⟨page number⟩,⟨type⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}

    %   
    %   \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    %   {1} %  page number to be included
    %   {0.9} % scale
    %   {true} %   landscape = true or false
    %   {false} %  turn = true or false
    %   {subsection,2} % level in TOC: section, subsection, subsubsection + level 1,2,3
    %   {TitleTOC} %  heading for TOC / list 
    %   {Label} %   label: label-toc-#7, label-list-#7, #7-target for hyperlinks
    %   {table} %   addtolist = table or figure
    %   {mindmaps.pdf} %  file


    \def\MYpagesPDF{2}  
    \def\pageAddtoTOC{2}
    \def\pageAddtoList{2}

    \newcommand{\IncludeMyPDFThatBugs}[9]{%
    \newpage\hypertarget{#7-target}
    {\includepdf[pages={#1},nup=1x1,
        scale=#2,landscape=#3,turn=#4,
        pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
        addtotoc={\pageAddtoTOC,#5,#6,label-toc-#7},
        addtolist={\pageAddtoList,#8,#6,label-list-#7}]
    {#9}}}
    %---------------------------- end macro for including a PDF document

    \title{Title of book}
    \author{Author of book}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter 
    \maketitle
    \cleardoublepage
    \dominitoc
    \dominilof 
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \cleardoublepage

    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \minitoc
    \cleardoublepage
    \section{Section one Chapter one}
    \lipsum


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {\MYpagesPDF}
    {1}
    {false}
    {false}
    {subsection,2}
    {\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}}
    {table-mind-one}
    {table}
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a}{Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}}
    {figure-mind-one}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}



    \chapter{Chapter two}
    \minitoc
    \cleardoublepage        
    \section{Section one Chapter two}
    \lipsum
    \section{Section two Chapter two}
    \lipsum


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question}
    {figure-mind-two}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2} 
    {\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question}
    {table-mind-two}
    {table} 
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {\FrancaisEnglishSubSections{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question} 
    {nrp-algo}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}



    \cleardoublepage
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}



    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}


    \cleardoublepage


    \end{document}
```

I cloned the code, and took out the language selection. It compiled well afterwards. But - I have to keep the language selection - how could I improve it to make it work adequately ?

```
            %!TEX TS-program = pdflatex

    \PassOptionsToPackage{table,x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}

    \documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,usletter]{book}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}         

    \hypersetup{
         backref=true,   
         pagebackref=true, 
         hyperindex=true,  
         colorlinks=true,  
         breaklinks=true,  
         urlcolor= blue,   
         linkcolor= purple,  
         bookmarks=true,  
        pdftoolbar=true,        
        pdfmenubar=true,        
         bookmarksopen=true,            
         pdftitle={title of book},  
         pdfauthor={author of book},    
         pdfsubject={subject of book}
              } 


    %---------------------------- begin selection of language
    %  2 languages, here = second language selected
    \mtcselectlanguage{english}   % for minitoc

    %   \def\ColorSecondLanguage{\textcolor{DarkViolet}}  % produces an error, why ?
    %   \def\ColorSecondLanguage{}

    %\newcommand{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage}[2]{\ColorSecondLanguage{#2}}
    %\newcommand{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage}[2]{#2}



    %---------------------------- begin macro for including a PDF document
    % includepdf syntax:
    %     addtotoc={⟨page number⟩,⟨section⟩, ⟨level⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}
    %     addtolist={⟨page number⟩,⟨type⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}

    %   
    %   \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    %   {1} %  page number to be included
    %   {0.9} % scale
    %   {true} %   landscape = true or false
    %   {false} %  turn = true or false
    %   {subsection,2} % level in TOC: section, subsection, subsubsection + level 1,2,3
    %   {TitleTOC} %  heading for TOC / list 
    %   {Label} %   label: label-toc-#7, label-list-#7, #7-target for hyperlinks
    %   {table} %   addtolist = table or figure
    %   {mindmaps.pdf} %  file


    \def\MYpagesPDF{2}  
    \def\pageAddtoTOC{2}
    \def\pageAddtoList{2}

    \newcommand{\IncludeMyPDFThatBugs}[9]{%
    \newpage\hypertarget{#7-target}
    {\includepdf[pages={#1},nup=1x1,
        scale=#2,landscape=#3,turn=#4,
        pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
        addtotoc={\pageAddtoTOC,#5,#6,label-toc-#7},
        addtolist={\pageAddtoList,#8,#6,label-list-#7}]
    {#9}}}
    %---------------------------- end macro for including a PDF document

    \title{Title of book}
    \author{Author of book}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter 
    \maketitle
    \cleardoublepage
    \dominitoc
    \dominilof 
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \cleardoublepage

    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \minitoc
    \cleardoublepage
    \section{Section one Chapter one}
    \lipsum


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {\MYpagesPDF}
    {1}
    {false}
    {false}
    {subsection,2}
    {Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}
    {table-mind-one}
    {table}
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}{figure-mind-one}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}



    \chapter{Chapter two}
    \minitoc
    \cleardoublepage        
    \section{Section one Chapter two}
    \lipsum
    \section{Section two Chapter two}
    \lipsum


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}
    {figure-mind-two}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2} 
    {Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}
    {table-mind-two}
    {table} 
    {mindmaps.pdf}


    \IncludeMyPDFThatBugs
    {1}
    {0.9}
    {false}
    {true}
    {subsection,2}
    {Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}
    {nrp-algo}
    {figure}
    {mindmaps.pdf}



    \cleardoublepage
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}



    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}


    \cleardoublepage


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Both versions of your code produce the same warnings. Consider each `\IncludeMyPDFThatBugs` separately. Comment out all but that one. Note that for ones where it fails, you are trying to add an entry for page 2 in the `toc` but are only importing page 1. This is (at least part of) what `pdfpages` is complaining about.
Further, some of the places where you use `\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage` are missing closing braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow ! Right on the spot ! Thanks very much, cyberSingularity !

1. Main error = not all my PDF documents had 2 pages, whereas
   sometimes the command `\IncludeMyPDFThatBugs`  called for the first,
   and sometimes it called for the second page.
2. Many missing closing braces:

   - `{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{first language}{second language}}` had
     some missing closing braces.
   - `{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{\textbf{first}\textbf{language}}{\textbf{second}\textbf{language}}}` had some missing closing braces.
   - Elsewhere, in my main code, I had `\hyperlink{name-target}{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{}{}}`  with some missing closing braces.
   - Some missing closing braces at the end of the last argument of another of my "home-made" command, not related to \includepdf.

TextWrangler / View / Balance or Balance and fold can help in looking for the "missing closing braces". But, be sure to close TeXShop when doing that.

Here is my final code without bug: `\IncludeMyPDF`

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}

\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,usletter]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         

\hypersetup{
     backref=true,
     pagebackref=true, 
     hyperindex=true,  
     colorlinks=true,  
     breaklinks=true,  
     urlcolor= blue,   
     linkcolor= purple,  
     bookmarks=true,  
     pdftoolbar=true,        
     pdfmenubar=true,        
     bookmarksopen=true,            
     pdftitle={title of book},  
     pdfauthor={author of book},    
     pdfsubject={subject of book}
      } 


%---------------------------- begin selection of language
%  2 languages, here = second language selected
\mtcselectlanguage{english}   % for minitoc

\newcommand{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage}[2]{#2}



%---------------------------- begin macro for including a PDF document
% includepdf syntax:
%     addtotoc={⟨page number⟩,⟨section⟩, ⟨level⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}
%     addtolist={⟨page number⟩,⟨type⟩,⟨heading⟩,⟨label⟩}

%   
%   \IncludeMyPDF
%   {1} %  page number to be included
%   {0.9} % scale
%   {true} %   landscape = true or false
%   {false} %  turn = true or false
%   {subsection,2} % level in TOC: section, subsection, subsubsection + level 1,2,3
%   {TitleTOC} %  heading for TOC / list 
%   {Label} %   label: label-toc-#7, label-list-#7, #7-target for hyperlinks
%   {table} %   addtolist = table or figure
%   {mindmaps.pdf} %  file

\newcommand{\IncludeMyPDF}[9]{%
\newpage\hypertarget{#7-target}
{\includepdf[pages={#1},nup=1x1,
    scale=#2,landscape=#3,turn=#4,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    addtotoc={#1,#5,#6,label-toc-#7},
    addtolist={#1,#8,#6,label-list-#7}]
{#9}}}

%---------------------------- end macro for including a PDF document

\title{Title of book}
\author{Author of book}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\dominitoc
\dominilof 
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Chapter one}
\minitoc
\cleardoublepage
\section{Section one Chapter one}
\lipsum


\IncludeMyPDF
{2}
{1}
{false}
{false}
{subsection,2}
{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}}
{table-mind-one}
{table}
{mindmaps.pdf}


\IncludeMyPDF
{1}
{0.9}
{false}
{true}
{subsection,2}
{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a}{Hamlet speaks this on his entry to Act 3 scene 1}}
{figure-mind-one}
{figure}
{mindmaps.pdf}


\chapter{Chapter two}
\minitoc
\cleardoublepage        
\section{Section one Chapter two}
\lipsum
\section{Section two Chapter two}
\lipsum


\IncludeMyPDF
{1}
{0.9}
{false}
{true}
{subsection,2}
{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question}}
{figure-mind-two}
{figure}
{mindmaps.pdf}

\IncludeMyPDF
{1}
{0.9}
{false}
{true}
{subsection,2} 
{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question}}
{table-mind-two}
{table} 
{mindmaps.pdf}


\IncludeMyPDF
{2}
{0.9}
{false}
{true}
{subsection,2}
{\FirstLanguageSecondLanguage{Nam dui ligula, fringilla}{To be, or not to be, that is the question}}
{nrp-algo}
{figure}
{mindmaps.pdf}



\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}



\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```